# Angular - date picker disabled

Tags: angular

I have a date picker as shown below. However, I'm unable to select a date except today's date. Its somehow disabled and doesn't let me select a date.

[image]

Component template for this section is in below link but I've not been able to find the right place that disables picking a date other than today's date.

jsfiddle.net/whfes6bo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I only needed to nullify the parentEndDate and parentStartDate attributes to enable both start and end dates.

```
<acc-datepickermanual id="startDate" [editable]="editable" (dateChange)="onProgramDateChange($event, true)" [currentDate]="program.startDate"
[parentEndDate]="null" [parentStartDate]="null" [start]="true"></acc-datepickermanual>
```